# Rails timestamps for specific columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

I'm looking for a way to add a `*_updated_at` columns for several columns in a record.

It would work similarly to normal Rails timestamps, ie based on convention. If there's a DB column called `author_updated_at`, the class would automagically update it whenever `author` attribute changes.

Not too hard to write, but thought I'd ask here in case anyone has done it before or there's a gem around. I'd also be interested to know if there are any performance issues with this approach, though I think it should be negligible if using `before_save`. There's no extra reads or writes needed.

Comment: You don't need a gem, Vanilla Rails is enough. Use this [module](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) with a [callback](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-track-changes-with-after-callbacks-in-rails-3-or-newer/).. and you are done.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) - it tracks changes to a model but in a slightly different fashion - instead of adding extra columns for each attribute to track it uses a table to store versions of the model. This gives you a full blown versioning system without doing much work.

You can easily revert to previous versions and track who created a revision etc.

But if all you need is a light-weight solution to store a timestamp for the changes to a limited set of attributes you can use model callbacks to set the `*_updated_at` columns.

```
module AttributeTimestamps

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_validation(on: :update) do
      # Use ActiveModel::Dirty to get the changed attributes
      self.previous_changes.each_with_index do |attr|
        setter = "#{attr}_updated_at="
        self.call(setter, self.updated_at) if self.respond_to? setter
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AttributeTimestamps  
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for this more for performance optimisations rather than auditing though, so it wouldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved with a different version of @max solution.

`previous_changes` wasn't working for me. I'm using Rails 4.2.

```
module AttributeTimestampable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_save do
      self.changed.each do |attr|
        timestamp = "#{attr}_updated_at"
        update_column(timestamp, updated_at) if self.respond_to? timestamp
      end
    end
  end
end
```